# Android ProximityAlert does not stay active after exiting app (i.e. pressing home button)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, alert, proximity

I am able to set a proximity alert (i.e. generates a notification when the phone enters/exits specified radius) which works as I want only when I still have the app up. When I click home, the radius exit/enter conditions which normally fire the alert do not result in a notification.

I am pretty sure it has something to do with registering and unregister receivers, but I cannot figure it out. When I don't include a call to unregisterReceiver and press home, a leaked receiver error appears. When I include it in onPause() and click home, I get no errors, but the alert doesn't work.

Is there something I am not understanding about these proximity alerts? What is the best way to have an app respond to proximity as I wish it to?

Answer (score 0):

Register pending intent instead of receiver.   They survive application shutdown

Answer (score 0):

Register your BroadcastReceiver in the Manifest file. It will automatically register and unregister itself.

```
<receiver android:name="ProximityIntentReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.googlemaps.PROXIMITY_ALERT">
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

It will work even after the home button is pressed.